# Pronunciation of "lever"

Tags: pronunciation

You can hear different pronunciations of the mechanical component *lever*. Sometimes it is pronounced with an i-sound, similar as in "leave", and other times you hear it with a clear e-sound almost as in "heavy". 
Why is that? I doubt it could be explained by regional or personal differencies, since the same person can shift between the pronunciations. My guess is, that this difference lies in where the lever is in use. I haven't been able to see any clear pattern, though.

Comment: I will tend to switch based on the context. And I suspect that whether it's being used as a noun or a verb has some effect, though I can't nail it down.

Comment: I would say 'lever' in 'pull the lever' (on a machine) and 'lever up a paving slab' the same way.

Comment: US and UK tend to differ on this.

Comment: My British pronunciation of leverage, levering, levered, etc would also have the first 'e' as the 'ea' in 'leave'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Except for the abominable verb "to leverage" which I refuse to pronounce in a way that suggests it's part of proper English:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

US speakers tend to say the first 'e' of 'lever' as in bet, bed, met, etc, while speakers in the British English zone say that same syllable as the 'ea' in leave, meat, heat, etc. To Brits it sounds as if Americans are saying 'levver'.

> "since the same person can shift between the pronunciations".

This is very unusual. Native speakers tend to be consistent in pronouncing this word.

['Lever' US & British pronunciation examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/lever)

Answer (score 0):

Either pronunciation [lee-ver] or [le-ver] is understood. 
In Australia, it is pronounced more like [lee-va]

Comment: "In Australia, it is pronounced more like [lee-va]" Same in Britain, unless the speaker has a local accent which is rhotic (in which the letter 'r' is pronounced at the end of syllables, e.g. West Country).